# Myoblasts Formation

Tags: muscles, embryology, stem-cells

Myoblasts arise from mesenchymal stem cells (MSCs), and are precursors to myocytes. In muscles, in the basement membrane, there are also present satellite cells which can divide to generate muscle fibres, to repair injury to muscle. Are satellite cells intermediates in the lineage from MSCs to myocytes?

Is the lineage then MSC > Satellite cells (a committed stem cell or progenitor) > myoblast (precursor) > myocyte? 
If not, then what are the progenitors for myocytes, and how do satellite cells fit in this lineage?

Comment: Read https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4073943/